# Extract specific words from text in python using regular expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have the following text for example:

```
[ABC]something
    foo 25
    bar 20

[DEF]something
    foo 50
```

.....and other similar text like this

I want to extract the three words from the brackets, foo and bar and the digits so i can get the result of re.findall as something like this
`[('ABC', 'foo 25', bar 20'), ('DEF', 'foo 50')]`

I tried the following pattern, but returns many empty strings in list

```
\[(\w+)\]|\n\s+(\w+\s\d+)
```

Comment: Use two expressions or a parser altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
import re

data = """
[ABC]something
    foo 25
    bar 20

[DEF]something
    foo 50
"""

rx_outer = re.compile(r'''
    ^
    \[(?P<section>[^][]+)\]
    (?P<content>(?:.+[\r\n]?)+)
    ''', re.M | re.X)

rx_inner = re.compile(r'\w+\s+\d+')

result = []
for outer in rx_outer.finditer(data):
    section = outer.group('section')
    values = tuple([value.group(0) for value in rx_inner.finditer(outer.group('content'))])
    result.append((section,) + values)

print(result)
```

Or - as a list comprehension:

```
result = [(section,) + tuple([value.group(0) for value in rx_inner.finditer(outer.group('content'))])
          for outer in rx_outer.finditer(data)
          for section in [outer.group('section')]]

print(result)
```

Bot will yield

```
[('ABC', 'foo 25', 'bar 20'), ('DEF', 'foo 50')]
```

See the demo for the [**"outer"**](https://regex101.com/r/ILdGZI/1) and the [**inner**](https://regex101.com/r/ILdGZI/2) expressions, the rest is programming logic.

Comment: thanks, but that replicated 'ABC'.. i want it to be ('ABC', 'foo 25', 'bar 20') 

Comment: @user13711798: Ah, one moment then.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But this seems way more advanced for me. I was expecting to obtain results directly from re.findall. I will try to learn this in the meantime. Also sorry, it wont let me upvote :(.